# Transfer data from standard mysql server to Percona XtraDB Cluster

Tags: mysql-5.5, mysqldump, percona, xtradb-cluster

My old mysql 5.5 server is having some hardware issue, so now I'm going to setup a new Percona 5.7,  two node cluster in my environment and connect my app into it.

Now the problem is,  How should I transfer all my data in mysql 5.5 server into my cluster ? Both are having InnoDB engine.
Will that be possible to take a sql dump from my old server and directly restore that in one of the nodes in my new cluster ? Or else what is the safest and effective way ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have disk files, then the best would be to install 5.5 somewhere in order to get at the data.  5.7 is *probably* too advanced to be able to read 5.5 files without some hiccups.

If you have a data dump, then it will *probably* load into 5.7 with minimal hiccups.

A PXC node can be a Slave to your Master.  If we can get that set up, *and* if there are not conflicts with table names, etc, then we can feed the data into the cluster this way...  After setting up a Master with no data, "load" the data from a backup of your 5.5 data.  Probably (but I am not sure) a 5.5 Master should be able to replicate to a 5.7 Slave on a PXC cluster.

Or, it should be possible to simply load the backup directly onto any PXC node.  (Or the designated Master node, if you configured it that way.)

Do you have GTIDs enabled?  Galera type?  Or Oracle type?  (If enabled this may be another hiccup point.)

Sorry to be vague, but I hope I have given you some tips on where to look next.